# Magento 2: - Set WYSIWYG editor near to custom option in admin side

Tags: magento2, database, custom-options, wysiwyg

**We created text box near to custom option can it be possible to put wysiwyg?**

[image]

Code we use for that

**StackExchange\Affordablemantel\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
        <plugin name="stackexchange_affordablemantel_custom_option" type="StackExchange\Affordablemantel\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**StackExchange\Affordablemantel\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions.php**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Affordablemantel\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class CustomOptions
{

    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject,
        $meta
    ) {
        $meta['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']['container_option']['children']['container_common']['children']['custom_text'] =
        $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
            200,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                            'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/component/static-type-input',
                            'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                            'imports' => [
                                'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get config for "Title" fields
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTitleFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                            'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'custom_text',
                            'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => false
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

**create a column 'catalog_product_option' table same as field name. e.g: custom_text**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update your

> StackExchange\Affordablemantel\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions.php

File with below code

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Affordablemantel\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class CustomOptions
{

   public function afterModifyMeta(
       \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject,
       $meta
   ) {
       $meta['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']['container_option']['children']['container_common']['children']['custom_text'] =
       $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
           200,
           [
               'arguments' => [
                   'data' => [
                       'config' => [
                           'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                           'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/wysiwyg', // updated
                           'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                           'imports' => [
                               'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id'
                           ]
                       ],
                   ],
               ],
           ]
       );
       return $meta;
   }

   /**
    * Get config for "Title" fields
    *
    * @param int $sortOrder
    * @param array $options
    * @return array
    */
   protected function getTitleFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
   {
       return array_replace_recursive(
           [
               'arguments' => [
                   'data' => [
                       'config' => [
                           'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                           'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                           'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg::NAME, //updated
                           'dataScope' => 'custom_text',
                           'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg::NAME, //updated
                           'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                           'validation' => [
                               'required-entry' => false
                           ],
                       ],
                   ],
               ],
           ],
           $options
       );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/wysiwyg'` component.

Ref. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-wysiwyg.html